# Perl: Converting a date held in a string to a different format

Tags: perl, date

I have a date that I have extracted from a log file in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format.

I have it in a variable called `$field0` along with another nine variables `$field1` - `$field9`.

Using Perl I want to change the format of the string to `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS` and put it back in `$field0`

Surely there must be a really easy way to do this?

Can anyone assist please or point me somewhere that has am example?

Comment: It won't solve your problem but have you considered giving your fields better names than $field0 etc? How about $log_date or something that describes what it contains?

Comment: @mekazu - Yep did that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two obvious approaches. The first is to use the core [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module to parse the date-time string and reformat it, and the second is to use a regex substitution to match the three date fields and reverse them

Here are both techniques used in a single program

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

my $time0 = my $time1 = '2016-05-28 12:53:19';

$time0 = Time::Piece->strptime($time0, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')->strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S');
say $time0;

$time1 =~ s/^(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/$3-$2-$1/;
say $time1;
```

#### output

```
28-05-2016 12:53:19
28-05-2016 12:53:19
```